# Send json data from client to server using volley library

Tags: android, json, client, server, android-volley

I want to send a simple message from client to server (the server is not localhost). I use Volley library and the method POST.
When I run the code did not make the connection, LogCat prints:

```
05-30 12:19:05.930: D/memalloc(12085): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51dec000 size:3727360 offset:3112960 fd:48 
05-30 12:19:06.340: D/memalloc(12085): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5227a000 size:4382720 offset:3768320 fd:47
05-30 12:19:06.370: E/Volley(12085): [1] 2.onErrorResponse: Error:
```

**Client code:**

```
String url = "http://myWebServer.eu";
RequestQueue queue;
JsonObjectRequest request;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    map.put("param1", "example");

    request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, 

            url, 
            new JSONObject(map), 
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { 
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(7));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    queue.add(request);
}
```

**PHP Server code**

```
$jsondata = $_POST['param1'];

$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

echo $json ;
```

Comment: Did you set internet permission inside your Manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Here you try to decode non json type into json. The $post['param1'] is the string value which you can request form the your app to server just print $post['param1'] is the String format not a json

```
$jsondata = $_POST['param1'];

echo $json_encode($_POST)  ;
```

Comment: @ADamian can you post your logcat here

Comment: I think the problem is we are sending the response from the server is not json data and in the app volley library try to convert the data into the json object

Comment: In my code when i create new request, i create a new jsonobject.             "new JSONObject(map)"      and  the map is parameters for the php code.

Comment: volley JsonObjectRequest is only support json object from response not accepted this request simple string or not a json array in response

Answer (score -1):

in you php side write below code:

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$json = $value->param1;
```

and also you should send back json format for respone to your app, as you can see in this line ( public void onResponse(JSONObject response) )

also add header to your post:

```
@Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put( "charset", "utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
```